# android, drawable resource loaded to memory?

Tags: android, resources, drawable

does all resource (all in res folder if on eclipse IDE), specially drawable image, is loaded to memory during runtime? or it is just like a file which is available when the application need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources are loaded on demand only, so no extra memory use if you don't call them.

They are however in your application package, so they take up disk space.